# Creating multiple transactions in a single hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, transactions

I have created a Quartz Job which runs in background in my JBoss server and is responsible for updating some statistical data at regular interval (coupled with some database flags)

To load and persist the I am using Hibernate 4. Everything works fine except one hick up.

The entire thread i.e. Job is wrapped in a Single transaction which over the period of time (as the amount of data increases) becomes huge and worry some. I am trying to break this single large transaction into multiple small ones, such that each transaction process only a sub group of data.

Problem: I tried very lamely to wrap a code into a loop and start/end transaction at start/end of the loop. As I expected it didn't work. I have been looking around various forums to figure out a solution but have not come across anything that indicates managing multiple transaction in a single session (where in only 1 transaction will be active at a time).

I am relatively new to hibernate and would appreciate any help that points me to a direction on achieving this.

Update: Adding code demonstrate what I am trying to achieve and mean when I say breaking into multiple transaction. And stack trace when this is executed.

```
    log.info("Starting Calculation Job.");

    List<GroupModel> groups = Collections.emptyList();
    DAOFactory hibDaoFactory = null;
    try {
        hibDaoFactory = DAOFactory.hibernate();
        hibDaoFactory.beginTransaction();
        OrganizationDao groupDao = hibDaoFactory.getGroupDao();
        groups = groupDao.findAll();
        hibDaoFactory.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        hibDaoFactory.rollbackTransaction();
        log.error("Error in transaction", ex);
    }

    try {
        hibDaoFactory = DAOFactory.hibernate();
        StatsDao statsDao = hibDaoFactory.getStatsDao();
        StatsScaledValuesDao statsScaledDao = hibDaoFactory.getStatsScaledValuesDao();

        for (GroupModel grp : groups) {
            try {
                hibDaoFactory.beginTransaction();
                log.info("Performing computation for Group " + grp.getName() + " ["
                        + grp.getId() + "]");

                List<Stats> statsDetail = statsDao.loadStatsGroup(grp.getId());

                // Coputing Steps here

                for (Entry origEntry : statsEntries) {
                    entry.setCalculatedItem1(origEntry.getCalculatedItem1());
                    entry.setCalculatedItem2(origEntry.getCalculatedItem2());
                    entry.setCalculatedItem3(origEntry.getCalculatedItem3());

                    StatsDetailsScaledValues scValues = entry.getScaledValues();
                    if (scValues == null) {
                        scValues = new StatsDetailsScaledValues();
                        scValues.setId(origEntry.getScrEntryId());
                        scValues.setValues(origEntry.getScaledValues());
                    } else {
                        scValues.setValues(origEntry.getScaledValues());
                    }
                    statsScaledDao.makePersistent(scValues);
                }

                hibDaoFactory.commitTransaction();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                hibDaoFactory.rollbackTransaction();
                log.error("Error in transaction", ex);
            } finally {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error", ex);
    } finally {

    }

    log.info("Job Complete.");
```

Following is the exception stacktrace I am getting upon execution of this Job

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createCriteria(SessionImpl.java:1555)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor469.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at $Proxy308.createCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at com.blueoptima.cs.dao.impl.hibernate.GenericHibernateDao.findByCriteria(GenericHibernateDao.java:132)
    at com.blueoptima.cs.dao.impl.hibernate.ScrStatsManagementHibernateDao.loadStatsEntriesForOrg(ScrStatsManagementHibernateDao.java:22)
    ... 3 more
```

To my understanding from what I have read so far about Hibernate, sessions and transactions. It seems that when a session is created it is attached to the thread and lives through out the threads life or when commit or rollback is called. Thus, when the first transaction is committed the session is being closed and is unavailable for the rest of the threads life.

My question remains: How can we have multiple transactions in a single session?

Comment: So what do you do if the second (third, fourth) "transaction" fails? What do you do with the data from the previous ones? Sounds like a hack that could possibly mess up all your data. You shouldn't define your transactions according to performance but to the needs of your business rules. Start looking why the "get slow" (sounds very strange to me anyway).

Comment: And: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Its not a hack. The data itself is grouped by a key and each group can have data starting from few hundred records to a million ones. In case a specific transaction fails. Administrator is made aware of that and rest all groups must be processed and saved successfully. And I am using Postgres. So to summarize, transaction that completes successfully must be written to the database and ones that fails must be rolled back. This wont affect each other. I hope this explains my requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Your business rules either required everything to be in a single transaction, then breaking it up is a "hack". Or your business rules did not require this, then the existing code is wrong. To split a transaction (required by your business rules) into smaller ones, *is* incorrect - especially if it's only for performance.

Comment: "it didn't work". Er .... details? **Error messages**? Exact PostgreSQL version? **The code**?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had everything in a single transaction was to get the first prototype version ready, I am relatively new to Hibernate and hence am taking baby steps. In this single transaction version as well, the computations on each groups are independent. And so the persistence can happen independent as well, as in independent transactions.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have updated the question and added Sample Code and Error message.

Answer (score 2):

More detail would be great and some examples but I think I should be able to help with what you have written here.

Have one static SessionFactory (this is big on memory)
Also with your transactions you want something like this.

```
SomeClass object = new SomeClass();

Session session = sessionFactory().openSession() // create the session object
session.beginTransaction(); //begins the transaction
session.save(object); // saves the object But REMEMBER it isn't saved till session.commit()
session.getTransaction().commit(); // actually persisting the object
session.close(); //closes the transaction
```

This is how I used my transaction, I am not sure if I do as many transaction as you have at a time. But the session object is light weight compared to the SessionFactory in memory.

If you want to save more objects at a time you could do it in one transaction for example.

```
SomeClass object1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass object2 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass object2 = new SomeClass();

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(object1);
session.save(object2);
session.save(object3);
session.getTransaction().commit(); // when commit is called it will save all 3 objects
session.close();
```

Hope this help in some way or points you in the right direction. 
I think you could configure you program to condense transactions as well. :)

*Edit*
Here is a great youtube tutorial. This guy really broke it down for me.

[Hibernate Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4AFF701184976B25)